# Interactive credentials for Azure Blob

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I got this code to obtain interactive credentials (this prints a url, and a device code to login) in Jupyter Notebook:

```
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import AADTokenCredentials
import adal, uuid, time

def authenticate_device_code():
    """
    Authenticate the end-user using device auth.
    """
    authority_host_uri = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com'
    tenant = 'tenant_id'
    authority_uri = authority_host_uri + '/' + tenant
    resource_uri = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
    client_id = 'client_id'

    context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_uri, api_version=None)
    code = context.acquire_user_code(resource_uri, client_id)
    print(code['message'])
    mgmt_token = context.acquire_token_with_device_code(resource_uri, code, client_id)
    credentials = AADTokenCredentials(mgmt_token, client_id)

    return credentials
```

Once authenticated, it returns a AADTokenCredentials object.

The question is whether I can use this to access Blob Store:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
service = BlobServiceClient(account_url=uri, credential=credentials)
```

According to the docs, `BlobServiceClient` only accepts a SAS token or an instance of a TokenCredentials class, but I could not find a way to use interactive authentication with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AAD token authentication is supported. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#types-of-credentials).

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(
    account_url="https://<my_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net",
    credential=token_credential
)
```

To use Device code auth, you would replace`token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()` with `DeviceCodeCredential` from [here](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-identity/1.2.0/azure.identity.html#azure.identity.DeviceCodeCredential).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried InteractiveBrowserCredential before, but it is trying to open a new browser windows that doesn't seem to work from notebooks.

Comment: ah, can you try to use `DeviceCodeCredential` instead? https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity#credentials

Comment: glad to hear it! I fixed the answer